# If I set up a user in sandbox will it use one of my production licenses?

Tags: sandbox, licenses

I have a full copy sandbox. I now have a user that wants to explore the org and try some things out however, I don't want them to do this is the production org. Therefore I need to set them up in the sandbox. If I set them up in the Sandbox, will the license allocated to them be taken from my production org licenses?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, sandboxes do not count against your production license limit.  However, within the sandbox you'll still need to stay within your overall limit.  Since it's a sandbox, if you run low just deactivate some users who don't need access to the sandbox.

For example, if you have 2 free licenses in production and create a sandbox, you'll start with 2 free licenses in the sandbox.  After creating a user in the sandbox you'll have 2 free licenses in production and 1 free in the sandbox.  Once you hit the limit in the sandbox you'll need to deactivate users.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that those users will vanish if you refresh the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

No.

It is not taken from Production Org licenses.
In sandbox you get same number of licenses as in production and you can use those licenses,